# Why refreshing the ApplicationContext immediately after its creation in WebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: spring-mvc

In https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html 11.1 there is an example:

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletCxt) {

        // Load Spring web application configuration
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ac.register(AppConfig.class);
        ac.refresh();
      ...
```

Then in chapter 11.4 there is another example but without the ac.refresh();

What benefit could refreshing the context immediately after its creation possibly have?

Answer (score 0):

After calling `refresh()` it would be possible to get all configured contents from the ApplicationContext (beans, listeners, resources, etc.).

For instance, without refreshing the context any call to `ac.getBean("myBean")` would throw

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
       BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh'
       before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

Usually in `WebApplicationInitializer` there is no need to get beans or other configured items, because its purpose is configuration of servlets and filters for the web application. That's why calling `refresh` is not necessary here.